# Interaction between 2 tables in 2 frames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

What kind of frames/panes are the best practice to accommodate goal below?

- main frame has `jtable1`
- pressing `ENTER` on `jtable1` will call sub frame
- sub frame has `jtable2` with 2 rows data
- both `jtable1` and `jtable2` has exact same column names

By pressing `ENTER` on row 2 of `jtable2`, these below will happen:

- value of current row of `jtable1` = value of row 2 of `jtable2`
- `jtable1` will create new row
- dispose sub frame

Comment: Why have two tables? Why not just have one and swap the models?

Comment: *"..should probably appear in a (modal) `JDialog`"* .. or what @MadProgrammer suggested (change the model in one table), which sounds better.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, jtable1 is the main table, when need looking up for desired item (ex. select productname from master where productid like '%pencil%'), user need to find it in frame2 n put the desired items on jtable2, then user can choose which item is needed from jtable2, then transfer its value to jtable1 and jtable2 is disposed and back to jtable1.

Comment: @andrew, There is actually a textfield in frame2 as input (pencil as input) for (select productname from master where productid= like '%pencil%').
there will b several results which is put in jtable2.
then user will choose which pencil is needed from jtable2 n transfer its value to jtable1 by pressing ENTER b4 disposing frame2. then go back to jtable1 in frame1 n continue for other product.
I'll try using jdialog / joptionpane as you suggest, hoping that it'll work.

Comment: @andrew, thank you, (modal) Jdialog is the best option because it prohibit access to other frame till its closed.  It took me a week to solve it at last. Components' variables is kind of complicated with multi frame. Is it allowed to share the code as answer to my own post here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample which could be an answer to question above:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Dialog3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        //f1=JFrame 1, f1cp=ContentPane in f1, f1table=JTable in f1, f1sp=ScrollPane in f1
        JFrame f1=new JFrame("Frame");
        f1.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 400);
        f1.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel f1cp=new JPanel();
        f1.getContentPane().add(f1cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        String[] columnNames = {"CODE", "NAME"};
            Object[][] data = {{"code 8","name 8"}, {null,null}};
            DefaultTableModel f1model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
            JTable f1table=new JTable(f1model);
        JScrollPane f1sp=new JScrollPane(f1table);
        f1cp.add(f1sp);

        f1.pack();
        f1.setVisible(true);        

        f1table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed ENTER"), "f1enter");
        f1table.getActionMap().put("f1enter", new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){showd1(f1,f1table, f1model);}
        }); 

    } //end of main(string[])

    private static void showd1(JFrame f1, JTable f1table, DefaultTableModel f1model){
        //d1=JDialog1, d1cp=ContentPane in d1, d1table=JTable in d1, d1sp=ScrollPane in d1
        JDialog d1=new JDialog(f1, "Dialog", true);
        d1.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 400);
        d1.setLocationRelativeTo(f1);

        JPanel d1cp=new JPanel();
        d1.getContentPane().add(d1cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        String[] columnNames = {"CODE", "NAME"};
            Object[][] data = {{"code 1","name 1"}, {"code 2","name 2"}};
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
            JTable d1table=new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane d1sp=new JScrollPane(d1table);
        d1cp.add(d1sp);

        d1table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed ENTER"), "d1tf");
        d1table.getActionMap().put("d1tf", new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                f1table.setValueAt(d1table.getValueAt(d1table.getSelectedRow(), 0),f1table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
                f1table.setValueAt(d1table.getValueAt(d1table.getSelectedRow(), 1),f1table.getSelectedRow(), 1);
                f1model.addRow(data);   
                f1table.setValueAt(null, f1model.getRowCount()-1, 0);
                f1table.setValueAt(null, f1model.getRowCount()-1, 1);
                d1.dispose();
            }
        });

        d1.pack();
        d1.setVisible(true);        
    } //end of showd1
}
```